# CMake: Why is an added_subdirectory not visible to other subdirectories

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following project structure:

```
project
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - src
  - LibA
    - CMakeLists.txt
  - LibB
    - CMakeLists.txt
```

The root CMakeLists.txt looks kind of like this:

```
add_subdirectory(LibA)
add_subdirectory(LibB)
add_executable(foo src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo LibA LibB)
```

However, LibB actually wants to use some functionality from LibA as well. However, I cannot access LibA from within LibB. But I can't add it as a subdirectory either. This is a real problem for me. How can I best solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "However, LibB actually wants to use some functionality from LibA as well. However, I cannot access LibA from within LibB." - Why cannot you access libA? What is wrong with `target_link_libraries(LibB LibA)` in the `LibB/CMakeLists.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a bit complex to tell, but I wish to explain it in a simplified way...

The project structure should be:

```
 /src
   |
   +-- /lib-a
   |     +-- /includes
   |     +-- /sources
   |     +-- LibAConfig.cmake
   |     \-- CMakeLists.txt
   +-- /lib-b
   |     +-- /includes
   |     +-- /sources
   |     +-- LibBConfig.cmake
   |     \-- CMakeLists.txt
   \-- /main
   |     +-- /includes
   |     +-- /sources
   |     \-- CMakeLists.txt
   \-- CMakeLists.txt
```

**/src/lib-a/LibAConfig.cmake** should be:

```
# Debug

MESSAGE ("-- Library A configuration...")

# Headers

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/includes)
```

**/src/lib-a/CMakeLists.txt** should be:

```
# Define project

project(LibA CXX)

# Debug

message("-- Working on \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}\"...")

# Package registration

set(LibA_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} CACHE INTERNAL "")

# Project files

include_directories(includes)
file(GLOB _SOURCES sources/*.cpp)

# Go on with your module setup...
```

**/src/lib-b/LibBConfig.cmake** should be:

```
# Debug

MESSAGE ("-- Library B configuration...")

# Headers

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/includes)
```

**/src/lib-b/CMakeLists.txt** should be:

```
# Define project

project(LibB CXX)

# Debug

message("-- Working on \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}\"...")

# Package registration

set(LibB_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} CACHE INTERNAL "")

# Project files

include_directories(includes)
file(GLOB _SOURCES sources/*.cpp)

# Reference/Link to LIB-A

find_package(LibA)

# Go on with your module setup...
```

**/src/main/CMakeLists.txt** should be:

```
# Define project

project(MainApp CXX)

# Debug

message("-- Working on \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}\"...")

# Project files

include_directories(includes)
file(GLOB _SOURCES sources/*.cpp)

# Reference/Link to LIB-A and LIB-B

find_package(LibA)
find_package(LibB)

# Go on with your module setup...
```

**/src/CMakeLists.txt** should be:

```
# Define project

project(MyProject CXX)

# Debug

message("-- Working on \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}\"...")

add_subdirectory(lib-a)
add_subdirectory(lib-b)
add_subdirectory(main)

# Go on with your module setup...
```

I have taken the above example from a project of mine...